# Ignoring white-spaces during pattern matching using a variable

Tags: regex, perl

Consider two files as below.

File1:

```
 Name : John Paul 
Address: 243,  First Floor,
          XYZ - 12345. 
Phone : 555  444 3333 
Name : Mison 
Address: some address like above 
Phone: 444 333 2222
```

File2:

```
Name: John Paul
Address: 243, First Floor,
         XYZ - 12345.
Phone: 555 444 3333
```

I am using Perl. Suppose am reading the first Name-to-Phone block from File2 and store it in `$var_file2` (concatenated by reading line by line). The contents of File1 are stored in `$var_file1` (slurped). Consider I need to compare the whole Name-to-Phone block from File2 with those in File1 and replace the match with another string. I used `quotemeta` function on `$var_file2` because the pattern match didn't work as such.

```
$q_var_file2 = quotemeta($var_file2);
$replace = "replace_text";
$var_file1 =~ s/$q_var_file2/$replace/s;
```

Now the above code works perfectly when the patterns match exactly. But there **may be additional or no spaces** in File1 or File2 between words/characters which need to be ignored while doing the pattern matching and replacement.

I tried with `\S` which matches only non-white-space. But I think I missed something. I even tried with using the variable without applying `quotemeta` on them.

Comment: I think you have chosen the wrong approach. These fields must have been entered by hand, so there can be a lot of variation other than spaces. Suppose your address had been entered as `243 First Floor` for instance. Then the match would fail because of missing commas. There will even by typing mistakes to take account of. What exactly is the problem you are solving? It sounds like you want to update a database with a change of address?

Comment: @Borodin The exact problem is quite confidential and sorry beyond my authority. That's why I had to use a similar problem context to explain. Actually, commas are not of concern. Only spaces are an issue. And I want to replace the whole Name-to-Phone block by another, not just a field like address in a block.

Comment: You might use two extra variables. Copy the two texts you have into them, then do a `s/\s+/ /g` on each. That will convert all whitespace sequences into a single space. Then do the matching on these variables. Another option is to do a `s/\s+/\\s+/g` over the `$q_var_file2(.*?)$q_name` part of the replace expression. Where does `$2` come from in the replacement part?

Comment: @AdrianHHH `$2` is the `$q_name` which comes from `$q_var_file2(.*?)$q_name` part. And can you explain a bit more on the second option?

Comment: @AdrianHHH I've edited the question to have a simple scenario. The from-start-to-end was actually unnecessary. So now I just need to ignore white spaces in `$q_var_file2` for pattern matching.

Comment: Given `$var_file1 =~ s/$q_var_file2/$replace/s` my idea was to change the contents of `$q_var_file2` so all whitespace sequences are replaced with a `\s+` that will match any number of white spaces within `$var_file1`. Hence `s/\s+/\\s+/g` which changes any white space sequence to the three characters: backslash, lower-s and plus.

Comment: @AdrianHHH Thanks for the idea. But i guess `s/\s+/\\s+/g` should not be applied to `$q_var_file2` since it's already a quoted string and so a white-space substitution looks like `\\s\+` instead of `\s+`. So `s/\s+/\\s+/g` must be applied to `$var_file2` right? Therefore am using `$var_file1 =~ s/$var_file2/$replace/s` but nothing happens. Does it have something to do with newline characters? But they are also replaced by `\s+`.

Comment: `$var_file2` has real whitespace that is not altered when the `quotemeta($var_file2)` is used. I think the `s/\s+/\\s+/g` should be applied to `$q_var_file2`. Try all variations. With these complicated operations you should test on small datasets and print all the values as the code proceeds so you can see what is happening and when. More importantly, such prints allow you to see when unexpected changes happen and when expected changes do not happen. (Rather than `print` you may find that `Data::Dump` gives a better output.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54643/discussion-between-chris-petrus-and-adrianhhh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhhhm, you just want to replace all contiguous sequences of whitespace in `$var_file2` with `\s+`, while ensuring all other characters are run through `quotemeta`.

```
$q_re_file = join q{\s+}, map {quotemeta} split /\s+/, $var_file2;
```

or

```
$q_re_file = join q{\s+}, map quotemeta, $var_file2 =~ /\S+/g;
```

or

```
$q_re_file = $var_file2;
$q_re_file =~ s/(\S+)/quotemeta $1/ge;
$q_re_file =~ s/\s+/\\s+/g;
```

etc. etc.

and use `$q_re_file` as your regex.

Comment: Thank you very much, this works! But say in the worst case there is a `FirstFloor` in `File1` and in `File2` we have `First Floor` which mean the same, so this must give a positive match. Hence, in general we must ignore all spaces in `File1` and `File2` and match all other characters. Is there a way of solving this too along with your approach?

Comment: @ChrisPetrous Instead of `\s+` (one or more whitespace characters) in the final regex, use `\s*` (zero or more whitespace characters). Job done.